# Linq Comment VB

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, comments

How do you retrieve a comment from an XMLElement using Linq in VB?  For example:

```
<MyXML>
  <event type="MyEvent" uid="3">
    <start>2009-02-01T12:00:00</start>
    <stop>2009-02-01T12:00:30</stop>
    <New>1</New>
    <x>20</x>
    <y>60</y>
    <!--Whatever-->
  </event>
  <event type="MyEvent" uid="3">
    <start>2009-02-01T11:00:00</start>
    <stop>2009-02-01T11:00:30</stop>
    <New>3</New>
    <x>21</x>
    <y>67</y>
    <!--Second Whatever-->
  </event>
</MyXML>
```

If I wanted to loop through the events and retrieve the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `XmlElement`, or `XElement`? With XElement you could just use

```
element.DescendantNodes().OfType(Of XComment)()
```

(I hope that's the right syntax for generics - in C# it would be `OfType<XComment>()`.)

Comment: Does not appear to work.  Using XML above and this code
    Dim doc As XDocument
    Dim element As XElement
    Dim item As XComment
    doc = XDocument.Load("C:\Junk\MyXML.xml")
    For Each element In doc.Root.Elements
      For Each item In element.Descendants().OfType(Of XComment)()
        Debug.Print("here")
        Debug.Print(item.Value.ToString)
      Next
    Next
It never reaches Here.  It is like the comments are not loaded in.

Comment: Shoot - I do not seem to have rep enough to edit my comment, and it knocked out the code formatting in this comment.  But the suggestion does not appear to work unless I am missing something.

Comment: Never mind - your answer is basically correct.  I was using descendants and not descendant Nodes.  This works

 For Each item In element.DescendantNodes().OfType(Of XComment)()

Comment: Just a note: comments are not editable. You can delete it and repost it with the changes needed